# Не появляется сообщение в консоли после инжекта

Tags: c++, dll

Решил научиться писать DLL, просто ради интереса посмотреть, что из этого получится. Нашёл несколько видео по этой теме и, начал пытаться разбираться в том, что собственно пишет данный человек, спустя 3 просмотра данного видеоролика я преступил к коду, но писал его не на игре, которая светилась в видео (Просто потому что я не люблю повторять всё 1 в 1). В результате вышло следующее:
Hack.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "ExMachina.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
```

Создание потока.

```
DWORD WINAPI ExMachina_Thread(LPVOID lpReserved);
```

Внедрение.

```
DWORD APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved) {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        CreateThread(NULL, NULL, ExMachina_Thread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return true;
};
```

Дальше метод вызова консоли.

```
void CreateConsole() {
    int hConHandle = 0;
    HANDLE lStdHandle = 0;
    FILE *fp = 0;
    AllocConsole();
    SetConsoleTitle("ExMachina Debug");
    lStdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    hConHandle = _open_osfhandle(PtrToUlong(lStdHandle), _O_TEXT);
    fp = _fdopen(hConHandle, "w");
    *stdout = *fp;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
}
```

Ну и соответственно сам поток и его функции:

```
DWORD WINAPI ExMachina_Thread(LPVOID lpReserved) {
    CreateConsole();
    DWORD Address = (DWORD)GetModuleHandle("hta.exe") + 0x6135E4;
    ExMachina* EXMACHINA = ExMachina::Singleton(Address, 0x118);
    for (;;Sleep(75)) {
        printf("Succesfly inject 0x%x", EXMACHINA);
        std::cout << "Succesfly inject 0x%X", EXMACHINA;
    }
}
```

Как можно увидеть из подключенных библиотек есть и stdio.h и iostream, но ни то, ни другое информацию, которая мне нужна, не выводит. Что можно с этим сделать?

Comment: Можно разбирать с хвоста - Консоль появилась?

Comment: Можно разбирать с головы - DLL ваша загрузилась? Можно посмотреть... допустим старой ProcessExplorer от Sysinternals. Может у вас не хватет прав на внедрение.

Comment: @nick_n_a Консоль появилась.

Comment: И да, DLL, судя по ошибке которая возникает в случаи повторной компиляции dll при инжекте из папки Visual студии, загрузилась в игру.

Comment: Зачем так тяжело (делать `FILE *`) попробуйте вбить устаревшую `_lwrite((int)lStdHandle, "Hello", 5);` Используйте обычный `WriteFile`. Если напишет Hello - то переделывайте вывод. Я так сложно вывод в консоль ниразу не делал.

Comment: Вместо `printf` используйте `wsprintfA`(user32.dll) тогда вам не нужно мучать  stdio.h и iostream `char buff[100]; _lwrite((int)lStdHandle,buff,wsprintfA(buff,"format", ... ));`

Comment: `Sleep(75)` пауза 75мсек

Comment: wsprintfA тоже не сработало.

Comment: А если поставить Hello - срабатывает?

Comment: А... если ExMachina::Singleton валит exception... то... то тогда незнаю как вам помочь. Попробуйте обвернуть в try-catch.

Comment: Нет, ошибку оно не ловит :(

Comment: Ставьте простые маячки (много) - смотрите - отлаживайте. Невозможно угадать в какой части ваша программа затыкается. Ещё вариант - хост может запросить состояние thread и значение регистров. Возможно у вас получится через механизм Remote считать регистры, и стек вызовов - по ним можно понять где заткнулось. Состояние бывает Suspended, Running, Error. По состоянию тоже можно сделать вывод.

Comment: Возможно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949725/how-to-get-thread-state-e-g-suspended-memory-cpu-usage-start-time-priori эта статья вам поможет.

Comment: Тут мало информации что б понять как эту проблему решить. Возможно дополнив состоянием thread и стак-трейсом - будет сразу ясно в чем проблема. Через стак-трейс - прийдётся расшифровать цепочку вызовов вручную. Для этого вам понадобятся ф-ции `GetThreadContext` и `ReadProcessMemory` в инжекторе + знание значений регисров, в частости eip и esp. Маячками возможно будет проще.

Comment: а пробовали вместо консоли MessageBox открыть?

Comment: Слушай, я чет совсем нифига не вдупляю, я скопировал этот же код в Dev c++ - консоль заработала! Но! Когда я пытался добавить смещение по формуле `return(ExMachina**)(((DWORD*)Address)+offset); ` он не мог добавить offset нормально, но когда я при выводе добавил смещение - пожалуйста, вот вам, верный адрес. Да как это работает то вообще?  То на ровном месте не работает, то работает но не так, что не так то с этим C++?!

Comment: @goldstar_labs нет, кстати, хотя стоило бы, наверно...

Comment: С С++ все так, инъекции не самая простая тема, чтобы так с наскоку по видосикам на ютубе их осилить) Важно как слинкована ваша ДЛЛ (я не помню конфликтуют ли /MT /MD), как она инъектируется, как подгружается и т.п. Чтобы понимать, что происходит, вам надо почитать о структуре .exe файлов, как система определяет зависимости .exe файлов и как собственно происходит процесс загрузки исполняемого файла в память. Возможно вас это утешит, но прежде чем написать первый работающий чит вы наступите на все грабли и набьете все шишки, но дальше будет полегче